# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer' when trying transfer learning with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I'm trying to do transfer learning with keras model,
but got stuck on adding new layers to the model.
I've tried code below :

```
prev_model = load_model('final_model.h5') # loading the previously saved model.

new_model = Sequential()
new_model.add(prev_model)
new_model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
new_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
new_model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

but got :

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x00000000B74364A8>
```

It happens whenever i'm using `.add()` to add layers .

Then I found

```
number_of_layers_to_freeze = 10
vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False)
for i in range(number_of_layers_to_freeze):
    vgg_model.layers[i].trainable = False
vgg_output = vgg_model.outputs[0]
output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(vgg_output)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg_model.inputs, outputs=output)
```

at other post.
but it leads to

```
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
```

I'm currently using

```
keras 2.2.5 
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0
```

Is it caused by version conflict ?

---

full traceback :(AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer')

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-afcad6e65f32> in <module>
      4 #     vgg_model.layers[i].trainable = False
      5 vgg_output = conv_base.outputs[0]
----> 6 output = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate, name="dropout_out")(vgg_output)
      7 
      8 model1 = models.Model(inputs=conv_base.inputs, outputs=output)

G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    661               kwargs.pop('training')
    662             inputs, outputs = self._set_connectivity_metadata_(
--> 663                 inputs, outputs, args, kwargs)
    664           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    665           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, previous_mask)

G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _set_connectivity_metadata_(self, inputs, outputs, args, kwargs)
   1706     kwargs.pop('mask', None)  # `mask` should not be serialized.
   1707     self._add_inbound_node(
-> 1708         input_tensors=inputs, output_tensors=outputs, arguments=kwargs)
   1709     return inputs, outputs
   1710 

G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _add_inbound_node(self, input_tensors, output_tensors, arguments)
   1793     """
   1794     inbound_layers = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.layer,
-> 1795                                         input_tensors)
   1796     node_indices = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.node_index,
   1797                                       input_tensors)

G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    513 
    514   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 515       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    516       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    517 

G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    513 
    514   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 515       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    516       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    517 

G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in <lambda>(t)
   1792             `call` method of the layer at the call that created the node.
   1793     """
-> 1794     inbound_layers = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.layer,
   1795                                         input_tensors)
   1796     node_indices = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.node_index,

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
```

fulltraceback :(TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer.)

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-b5858637ba91> in <module>
      2 # model.add(prev_model)
----> 3 model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(name="gap"))
      4 model.add(Flatten(name="flatten"))
      5 if dropout_rate > 0:
      6     model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate, name="dropout_out"))

G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    131             raise TypeError('The added layer must be '
    132                             'an instance of class Layer. '
--> 133                             'Found: ' + str(layer))
    134         self.built = False
    135         if not self._layers:

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x00000000B74364A8>
```

Comment: Please post the full trackback here.

Comment: Traceback will also indicate line numbers of your source code. Could you mark the lines in the posted code to show where the Errors are thrown as well ?

Comment: For the `layer` attribute error, I suppose that `vgg_output` is not what you suppose it is. You should print it to make sure. For the `class Layer` error, I remember that Keras didn't like nested models (adding `prev_model` to your `Sequential` model) some times ago. Maybe you can investigate this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer
```

You have created model using *keras.models.Model* while you are adding a layer from *tensorflow.keras.layers*.
Note that *keras* and *tensorflow.keras* is different. Make sure that you stick with one of them.